# Fetching and modifying the child elements in an xml Document

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

Here is a tricky bit of situation. I have a webservice that returns an XML document. This XML document has a root element that is called `<Entities .... >` The Entities element has child elements called `<Article..>`. I need to modify one of the child elements of Article and "PUT" each article element back to the webservice. The reason why I can not post the whole document with Entities is because the webservice does not recognize the Entities as an object and I can not perform an update operation on it.

Below is the structure of the document received:

```
<Entities>
  <Article id="1">
    <Permissions>
      <Sla id="1">
        <name> first sla </name>
      </Sla>
      </Permissions>
    </Article>
  <Article id="2">
    <Permissions>
      <Sla id="2">
        <name> second sla </name>
      </Sla>
      </Permissions>
    </Article>
</Entities>
```

Below is the code that I have used to do the trick but I can fetch the Sla element. What I need to do is to get the Sla elements in each article and run a check against its id attribute. If the check comes true, I need to remove that Sla element along with all of its child elements. This is what I have done so far:

```
int pageNumber = 1;
bool entities = true;
while (entities)
{
url = "www.myurl.com";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "Get";
HttpWebResponse rep = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
doc.Load(rep.GetResponseStream());
rep.Close();
if (doc != null)
{
                XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Entities/Article");
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    XmlNode Slanode = null;
                    try
                    {
                         Slanode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Permissions/Sla[@id='" + sla.ToString() + "']");
                         Slanode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                         string finalXML = doc.OuterXml;
                         HttpWebRequest reqToUpdate = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                         reqToUpdate.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=UTF-8";
                         reqToUpdate.Method = "PUT";
                         byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(finalXML);
                         reqToUpdate.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                         Stream data = reqToUpdate.GetRequestStream();
                         data.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                         data.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                    }


                }


                pageNumber++;
                }
                else
                    entities = false;
            }


            }
```

I cant get the code to work because when I reach the

`Slanode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Permissions/Sla[@id='" + sla.ToString() + "']");`

it does not populate the Slanode and it returns null, when I checked the nodes in debug mode, the list was showing the following error:

`Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document. Error processing resource`

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Path is wrong

```
Slanode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Permissions/Sla[@id='" + sla.ToString() + "']");
```

should be

```
Slanode = node.SelectSingleNode("Permissions/Sla[@id='" + sla.ToString() + "']");
```

I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to re-write that with XElement, hopefully that works for you as XElement is what I understand.

First get the Article to remove:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(stream);
XElement articleToRemove = root.XPathSelectElement("//Article[Permissions/Sla/@id='"+sla.ToString()+"']");
if(null != articleToRemove)
    articleToRemove.Remove();
```

To make the loop readable, create a Put function:

```
private void Put(XElement article)
{
    Stream data = null;
    try
    {
        string finalXML = article.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
        HttpWebRequest reqToUpdate = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        reqToUpdate.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=UTF-8";
        reqToUpdate.Method = "PUT";
        byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(finalXML);
        reqToUpdate.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        data = reqToUpdate.GetRequestStream();
        data.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != data)
            data.Close();
    }
}
```

Then get the rest of the articles and upload them:

```
root.Descendants("Article").ToList().ForEach(a => Put(a));
```

Edit: To use XPath with XElement you need to use the following using:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```